# Install Windows from Linux using wimapply

Tags: windows-10, wim

I am looking for way to install Windows 10 from the Linux (I am currently using Arch Linux here) without having to create the bootable USB disk.

I noticed that there are an utility called **wimapply** that works on Linux and here is my current scenario.

I have an SSD on `/dev/sda` that already have an EFI Boot partition (`/dev/sda1`) and an NTFS partition for the system on (`/dev/sda2`)

If I run this command:

```
wimapply install.wim 1 /dev/sda2
```

Will it deploy the Windows image (`install.wim`) that I previously extracted from the Windows ISO into my partition `/dev/sda2`?

Comment: Because I wish to deploy from my Linux installation without having to create the bootable flashdisk since it is to slow to create one from the flash drives that I have.

Comment: Disregard my previous comment should have read the entire article I was reading before submitting that comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will it deploy the Windows image (install.wim) that I previously extracted from the Windows ISO into my partition /dev/sda2?

Yes, but in my experience, the Windows installation won't be bootable.

##### Install Windows from Linux without using `wimapply`

My recommendation would be to install Windows a different way. You can still install Windows from Linux without creating a separate bootable USB drive. See my answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/749508/14436

##### Install Windows from Linux using `wimapply`

If you really want to use `wimapply`, you'll have to do some extra steps afterward to make the Windows installation bootable.

To make this answer more useful to others, here are the full instructions to install Windows using `wimapply`:

1. Download Windows 10 ISO from https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows10ISO
2. Extract sources/install.wim from the ISO

   In Ubuntu I just right-click > *Open With Disk Image Mounter* and then copy the file to a different location
3. Install wimtools, e.g.

   ```
   sudo apt install wimtools
   ```
4. Prepare the destination

   I typically use GParted for this kind of work:

   1. Create some free space on the drive

      1. Open GParted and resize or delete one or more partitions then click *Apply All Operations* at the top. I'd recommend at least 80 GB of space for Windows 10.
   2. Create a new NTFS partition

      1. Right-click on unallocated space > *New* > *File system* > *ntfs* > *Add* then click *Apply All Operations* at the top
   3. Make the partition bootable

      This marks the partition as "active" in Windows

      1. Right-click the partition > *Manage Flags* > make sure *boot* is checked > *Close*
5. Use wiminfo to list the images in install.wim and figure out which one you want

   ```
   wiminfo install.wim
   ```
6. Write the Windows image using wimapply

   In my case, I wanted to write the Windows 10 Pro image which had in index of 6 (from the previous step) to the new NTFS partition I created at /dev/sda3:

   ```
   sudo wimapply install.wim 6 /dev/sda3
   ```
7. Make the new Windows installation bootable

   1. Install VirtualBox
   2. Create a VMDK file for the physical partition, e.g.

      ```
      sudo vboxmanage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename sda3.vmdk -rawdisk /dev/sda -partitions 3
      ```

      ⓘ The way this works is the VMDK is for the whole drive, but it will only allow the VM to read/write to the partitions you specify
   3. Change ownership of the VMDK file to your user

      ```
      sudo chown "$USER:" *.vmdk
      ```
   4. Give your user temporary access to the disk group

      ```
      sudo usermod -aG disk "$USER"
      newgrp disk
      ```
   5. Start VirtualBox

      ```
      virtualbox
      ```
   6. Create a new VM for Windows 10

      - *ISO Image* > Select the Windows 10 installation ISO you downloaded
      - **Check *Skip Unattended Installation***

        ⚠ If you miss this step, the Windows installer will erase your entire drive
      - Select *Use an Existing Virtual Hard Disk File* and browse to the VMDK file you created
   7. Boot the VM to the Windows installation disc
   8. Press a key when prompted to boot the Windows installation
   9. At the boot prompt, select *Repair your computer* > *Troubleshoot* > *Command Prompt*
   10. Get the letter of the Windows partition

       ```
       X:\Sources>diskpart
       DISKPART> list disk
       select disk 0
       list partition
       select partition 3
       detail partition
       ```

       (Change `select disk` and `select parition` as appropriate)

       The disk letter will be listed under `Ltr`. If you don't see anything, you can assign a letter, e.g.

       ```
       assign letter z
       detail partition
       ```
   11. Make sure the partition is active

       The partition should be active if you set the *boot* flag in GParted, but check it just in case:

       1. Still in diskpart, get the partition information again

          ```
          detail partition
          ```
       2. Check that it says `Active: Yes`
       3. If not, use this command to set it as active:

          ```
          active
          ```
   12. Exit diskpart

       ```
       exit
       ```
   13. Check the disk for errors

       ```
       chkdsk c: /f
       ```
   14. Create the boot sector

       ```
       bootrec /fixboot
       ```
   15. Create the boot files

       ```
       cd X:\windows\system32
       bcdboot.exe Z:\Windows /s Z: /f ALL
       ```

       (Replace `Z` as necessary)

       You should see this message:

       ```
       Boot files successfully created.
       ```
   16. Exit the command prompt

       ```
       exit
       ```
   17. Choose *Turn off your PC*
   18. Optionally, delete the VM from VirtualBox
   19. Exit VirtualBox. Don't boot the VM!
   20. Remove your user from the `disk` group

       ```
       sudo deluser "$USER" disk
       ```
8. Add a Windows entry to Grub

   1. Enable the OS prober

      ```
      sudo sh -c 'echo GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER="false" >> /etc/default/grub'
      ```
   2. Run `update-grub`

      ```
      sudo update-grub
      ```
9. Reboot your computer and choose the new Windows 10 menu entry from Grub

Comment: Really nice and clear explanation. Thanks for the tips.